# как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на блок button становился enabled

Tags: javascript, button

```html
<div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pullRight" disabled>Continue</button>
</div>
```

Имеются 3 блока `<а>` и одна кнопка `button` с атрибутом `disabled`
Мне нужно сделать, чтобы при нажатии на блоки `<а>` атрибут `button` изменился на `enabled`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("a").on("click", function(){
  $(".pullRight").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#">test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#">test2</a>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#">test3</a>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pullRight" disabled>Continue</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#" onclick="myFunction('button1')">111</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#"></a>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <button id="button1" type="button" class="btn btn-default pullRight" disabled>Continue</button>
</div>


<script>
function myFunction(id) {
document.getElementById(id).disabled = false;
}
</script>
```